# Can't Windows 8 Consumer Preview be installed in some other drive than C?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, windows-8-preview

I have downloaded Windows 8 Consumer Preview ISO file and burnt it into a DVD. First thing the DVD doesn't boot and also when I try to run the setup from the DVD it asks me to clean up space in my C drive (in which 5 GB is free of 24 GB) because the Windows 8 need 16 GB space. But there is no option to install it in some other drive. I can't clean up the drive C, because it contains my current OS (Windows 7). Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a separate C: drive from one of the other partitions or install in a VM is what I would recommend. Don't risk a PC you are using otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. On the main install screen, instead of choosing `Install Now` you should choose `Install on another partition`.

You can check the 3rd printscreen on [this page](http://www.afterdawn.com/news/article.cfm/2012/03/01/quick_guide_to_installing_windows_8_consumer_preview_in_dual-boot).

Comment: But it doesn't ask so "Install Now Or Install on another partition. When I run the setup, first it asks the key, then it asks me what you want to keep in windows 8 consumer preview, I choose "nothing" and then finally it says that I need to clean up drive C in order to install it.

Comment: Ah are you running the setup from Windows ? or are you booting from BIOS from the DVD ?

Comment: I am running the setup from Windows. As I have mentioned, the DVD doesn't boot.

Comment: Ah right, then that's why you can't choose to install it to another partition. I would install it on a VHD (Virtual Hard disk) http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx

Comment: Can u tell me how to make it boot simply ?

Comment: Tell me what do you mean "DVD doesn't boot"? Did you `burn` the ISO on a DVD in order to make it bootable? Did you select in your BIOS the order of booting devices so that your DVD-ROM boots first?

Comment: Yes, I burnt the ISO on a DVD. And I don't know how to select booting devices from the BIOS. I haven't done that before.

Comment: Ok than that's your problem! Depending on your PC model (BIOS version), when your computer is turned on, it tells you usually in one on the (lower) corners which F key you have to press in order to access Setup (F2, F12, etc). You have to be a little fast in order to push that key during the first screen, if not you have to try again. After entering setup, there has to be a BOOT menu, where you can change the BOOTing order of the devices. Here, you just have to make sure the DVD-ROM is in the 1st position... For how to change the order, the BIOS gives you on-screen explanations.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview in my D drive. And both the OSs are working fine.

Comment: No prob. Have fun! :)